# No such module 'Cocoa' in Swift Playground with OS X platform

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I use xcode 6.1 in normal but it gets a error suddenly.

It should import the Cocoa framework with OS X platform:

`import Cocoa`

And it has this problem with OS X platform only.

[image: No such module 'Cocoa' in Swift Playground with OS X platform]

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the XCode defaults worked for me:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Close XCode and from the terminal run:

```
 rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

Then reopen XCode and most times this fixes many Playground issues. I run this command quite frequently during an intensive Playground work session (sometimes as many as a few times per hour) and have found liberal use of removing the ModuleCache to solve a multitude of strange playground behaviors.

If you're still having issues after running the above command you can also try:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

and/or

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```